# Найти точку - сумма расстояний до которой от заданного набора точек минимальна

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Условный магазин стоит размещать поближе к центру города и складу, но подальше, например от свалки и тюрьмы...

Хочу написать функцию решающую так называемую ["Задачу Вебера с притяжением и отталкиванием"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%E2%80%94_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F), суть которой состоит в том что есть набор n-мерных точек, и набор их привлекательности(в том числе и отрицательной) и нужно найти такую точку(не обязательно из набора), сумма расстояний от которой до привлекательных объектов минимальна, а до отвратительных максимальна.

Расстояние между точками определяется по [Евклидову расстоянию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0#:%7E:text=%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%20(%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)%20%E2%80%94,%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%20%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0.&text=%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F,%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8.)

Для начала написал [Алгоритм Вайсфельда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80#%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) .  :

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




def weisfeld(vec, v_res):
    def dist(v1, v2):   #расстояние между точками
        v1=np.array(v1)
        v2=np.array(v2)
        return np.linalg.norm(v1-v2)
    sumZnam=0.0
    dist1=0.0
    nev_V_res=[0]* len(v_res)
    for i in range(len(vec)):  #перебираем точки
        dist1 = dist(vec[i], v_res) 
        sumZnam += 1./dist1   #знаменатель формулы Веисфельда
    for n in range(len(vec)):
        dist2 = dist(vec[n], v_res)
        
        for t in range(len(vec[n])):
            nev_V_res[t] = nev_V_res[t] + (( vec[n][t] / dist2 ) / sumZnam)
    return nev_V_res       
        
    
v1=[10, 1] #  одна точка
v2=[0, 0]#  вторая точка
v3=[10, -1]
v_res=[8, 1] #Точка из которой начинаем искать оптимальную точку


weis=weisfeld([v1, v2, v3], v_res)


plt.plot(v1[0], v1[1], 'ro')   
plt.plot(v2[0], v2[1], 'ro')
plt.plot(v3[0], v3[1], 'ro')
plt.plot(weis[0], weis[1], 'bo')
plt.show()
```

Он решает проблему, но только если нету отталкивания- все точки только привлекательные. А при попытке добавить отталкивание функция становится не выпуклой и нет гарантии, что не попадем в локальный минимум.

Да и как корректно добавить отталкивание не понятно. Пробовал симметрично отражать точку, которая отталкивает таким образом чтобы она как бы притягивала, но с другой стороны.

```
#заменим точку на симметричную относительно приближаемой для отталкивающих точек
def symmetry(vec, vec_symmetry):
    nev_vec=[0]* len(vec)
    for i in range(len(vec)):
        nev_vec[i] = vec_symmetry[i]*2 - vec[i]
        #nev_vec[i] = 1/nev_vec[i]
    return nev_vec
```

Нагуглить по теме ничего стоящего так и не удалось.

Каков алгоритм решения "Задачи Вебера с притяжением- отталкиванием"? В идеале с весами(мерами значимости) точек и запрещенными зонами. Может кто-то писал код(не важно на каком языке)- задача, на мой взгляд должна встречаться во многих сферах, поделитесь пожалуйста.

Иллюстрации (Зеленые это притягивающие точки. Красные отталкивающие. Синие -итеративное приближение искомой точки алгоритмом.):

Начинаем с точки [2, 2].

[image: Начинаем с точки [2, 2].]

То же самое только точка [0, 0] отталкивающая.

[image: То же самое только точка ноль, ноль отталкивающая.]

Как и предыдущее но стартуем с [-1, -1]

[image: Как и предыдущее но стартуем с [-1, -1]]

Стартуем с [-1, 0] попадаем в локальный минимум

[image: Стартуем с [-1, 0] попадаем в локальный минимум]

Comment: Как понять "_не корректно_"? Если вы получаете не тот результат, который ожидали, то приведите пример входных данных, данные которые возвращает ваша программа и данные которые вы ожидали увидеть.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Я почему-то думал что искомая точка должна стремиться к середине отрезка между 2-мя привлекательными точками. А на самом деле это не важно- можно построить магазин хоть в притык к складу, главное чтобы на линии между складом и центром города- сумма расстояний будет одинаковой.  Благодарю что открыли глаза- попробовал с тремя все работает хорошо- сейчас отредактирую вопрос. Подскажите как задать отталкивание.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, у вас где-то потерялся физический смысл задачи. Насколько я понимаю, в экономической географии силы притягивания и отталкивания не сводятся к евклидовому расстоянию на плоскости.

Давайте для определённости возьмём задачу где выбрать съемную квартиру. В точке 0.0 есть супермаркет, где всё есть (сильная притягивающая точка), но постоянно толкутся люди (слабое отталкивание). В точке (10,1) есть магазин, где продается еда на каждый день (слабое притяжение) но он не вызывает никакого негатива. И в координатах (10,-1) есть завод, где шум, гам, и работяги (сильная отталкивающая точка).

То, насколько сильно отталкивают и притягивают объекты, должны нам сказать социологи. Для вычисления потенциала притягивания и отталкивания я от балды взял механизм штрафов: чем дальше вы от притягивающей точки, тем жальче вам от неё удаляться, чем ближе вы к отталкивающей точке, тем больнее вам к ней приближаться.

Для притягивающей точки я заложил убывание штрафа к бесконечности - иначе нас бы давно всех порвало от тоски по какому-нибудь гипотетическому Уолл-Марту в гипотетическом Канзас-Сити.

```
# Штраф для функции притяжения - сначала нарастает, потом убывает. На большом расстоянии уже пофиг, что там притягивает.
def attract(power, distance):
    # притягивающая часть - квадратичная сигмоидная функция
    p1 = power*distance/np.sqrt(distance+1)
    # забывание - степенная функция
    p2 = p1*(1/(distance+1))
    return p2
# Штраф для отталкивания - постепенно убывает. 
def repell(power, distance):
    return power*(1/(distance+1))
```

[image: Притягивающий и отталкивающий потенциал]

Конкретный вид потенциалов для притяжения отталкивания я просто выдумал. По-хорошему, нужно проводить исследования среди реальных людей, насколько меняются их отношения к притягательным и отталкивающим местам с расстоянием.

Дальше понятно. Задать потенциал по сумме точек и найти локальный минимум. Глобальный минимум с такими потенциалами искать бесполезно, он находится на бесконечности.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, coords, attracting, repelling):
        self.coords = np.atleast_2d(coords)
        self.attracting_power = attracting
        self.repelling_power = repelling
    def potential(self, point):
        point = np.atleast_2d(point)
        distance = np.linalg.norm(point-self.coords)
        attracting_penalty = attract(self.attracting_power, distance) if self.attracting_power > 0 else 0
        repelling_penalty = repell(self.repelling_power, distance)
        return attracting_penalty + repelling_penalty

class Potential:
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = points
    
    def potential(self, v):
        resPot = 0.0
        for p in self.points:
            potential = p.potential(v) 
            resPot += potential
        return resPot
    def __call__(self, v):
        return self.potential(v)
```

Вернёмся к примеру.

```
supermarket = Point((0.0), attracting=10, repelling=0.5)
factory = Point((10, -1), attracting=0, repelling=5)
minishop = Point((10,1), attracting=3, repelling=0)

fn = Potential((supermarket, minishop, factory))
```

[image: Потенциал трёх точек]

Супермаркет и магазин создают локальные минимумы, фабрика создаёт локальный максимум.

Далее ищем ограниченный локальный максимум и вуа-ля! Жить надо возле супермаркета ))

```
spo.minimize(fn, x0=(1,0), bounds=((-5, 15), (-10, 10)))
```

Результат

```
      fun: 1.7733099211366816
 hess_inv: <2x2 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([1.54659745, 0.5809764 ])
  message: b'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'
     nfev: 210
      nit: 20
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([-3.93721209e-09, -4.60977379e-09])
```

[Jupyter Notebook c функциями и графиками](https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/blob/main/python/1259494/repelling_points.ipynb)

## UPDATE

Отвечаю на вопросы, заданные в исходном посте и в комментариях.

Насколько я понял, вы настроились решать именно задачу Вебера, в которой стоимость расположения определяется взвешенной суммой расстояний до фиксированных точек и спрашиваете об универсальном решателе.

1. В `scipy.optimize` есть функция [`minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) которая реализует несколько общих методов поиска минимума многомерной функции. В силу своей универсальности функция `minimize` не гарантирует нахождение глобального минимума даже без отталкивающих точек. Например, в конфигурации "кластер близких слабо притягивающих точек и удалённая супер-притягивающая точка" общий метод вполне может "застрять" в локальном минимуме в центре кластера, а не в глобальном возле супер-притягивающей точки.
2. С отталкивающими точками в задаче Вебера глобальный минимум может существовать только в том случае, если сумма позитивных весов по модулю больше суммы отрицательных. В противном случае отрицательные веса "перевесят" и глобальный минимум будет `-inf` на бесконечности. Это как бы намекает, что даже специализированный метод поиска минимумов в задаче Вебера может "сломаться". Добавление отталкивающих точек полностью меняет задачу.
3. Ну и в общем. Я категорически не согласен с применением простейшей линейной функции оценивания для реальных задач "пространственной" экономики. Функции оценивания, ИМХО, должны стремиться к константе на бесконечности - нам совершенно не важно, что там есть вдали. Есть и есть, как фон. Поэтому я за то, чтобы использовать сигмоидные функции, а это совсем другие методы поиска минимумов. Но и в этом случае универсальные минимизаторы из `scipy.optimize.minimize` смогут застрять в локальных минимумах.
4. Не существуют универсальные методы, которые гарантированно находят глобальный минимум. Глобальные минимумы могут находить только специализированные методы, заточенные под конкретную задачу. Но эти методы сразу перестают работать, как только меняется форма функции оценивания. Тот же метод Вайсфельда работает с притягивающими точками, но ломается при отталкивающих. С сигмоидными функциями оценивания он, возможно, справится, но для более конкретного ответа нужно смотреть доказательство сходимости этого метода, какие требования он предъявляет к норме.
5. Соответственно, я предлагаю вам попробовать использовать общие методы из `scipy.optimize`, и переходить к специализированным только тогда, когда вы наткнётесь на явные промахи.

Comment: Про магазин это пример- чтобы быстро понять в чем суть дела.  И у меня нету каких-то секретных целей(так что никакой Ошибки молотка). Я понял что есть много сфер где Задачи Вебера с притяжением- отталкиванием применима... Из того что сразу приходит в голову это Задача определения стоимости земли- из предполагаемого алгоритма, основываясь на данных о покупках земли можно попробовать заполнить стоимость неоцененных участков. Рекомендательные системы- лайки притягивают, дизлайки отталкивают- пользователи и итемы это случайно инициализированные точки...  Массу всего хочется погонять таким образом.

Comment: Что касается предложенного вами решения- благодарю за такой развернутый ответ. Оно, на мой взгляд, дает ограниченный ответ- решение для конкретной задачи(хотелось бы более общее решение).  И перебрасывает вопрос в сферу работы оптимизаторов spo.minimize. По умолчанию вроде используется Метод Нелдера — Мида, который так же застревает в локальных минимумах. Прочитаю про остальные методы позже(ранее не сталкивался), но, как и написано над вопросом, хотелось бы увидеть канонический ответ для надежного решения подобных задач, ответ который преодолевает проблему локальных минимумов...

Comment: Если принять что оптимизатор spo.minimize работает хорошо, то похоже можно решить задачу написав функцию(вот эту https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F0-306-48332-7_178 ) находящую разницу между суммой расстояний до притягивающих точек и суммой расстояний до отталкивающих точек и применить к ней spo.minimize со случайным x0 . (До вашего ответа не знал вообще что существует spo.minimize). Но он не работает хорошо(по крайней мере Метод Нелдера — Мида).

Comment: @Hertz я постарался ответить на ваши вопросы в тексте. Добавил раздел Update

Comment: Я с вами согласен по поводу 3-его пункта вашего update. Но явные промахи это локальные минимумы, когда мы снимаем квартиру например относительно близко ко двум заводам, только потому что из начальной точки видим между ними магазин.   Не могли бы объяснить- в вашем примере мы находим точку максимума для attract  и минимума для repell, а значит если мы пользуемся функцией, которая находит минимум нескольких функций(scipy.optimize.minimize) не нужно ли переворачивать attract?

Comment: Да и вопрос все же: Каков алгоритм решения "Задачи Вебера с притяжением- отталкиванием"?  Хотелось бы хотя бы на него ответ, раз не выйдет общий метод оптимизации найти для разных метрик.  Подозреваю(требует доказательств) что легко будет данный алгоритм расширить для любых монотонных метрик.

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим вариант с трассировкой лучей:

Все объекты изображаем на карте с учетом их реальных размеров.
Из каждой точки карты выпускаем N=60 (например) лучей по всем направлениям.

Для каждого луча смотрим на список объектов, куда этот луч попал суммируем очки.
В конце, суммируем очки по всем лучам для этой точки.

В этом примере все объекты на карте кроме веса получают реальные физические размеры, таким образом маленький сортир и огромный завод будут создавать вокруг себя более реалтстичный потенциал вони (а далеко стоящий сортир алгоритм вообще не заметит)

Дальше, можно усложнить алгоритм, добавив на карту дороги, и тогда вместо лучей нужно будет трассировать уже вдоль дорог, составляя список посещенных объектов ("Куда из этой точки можно приехать?").

Comment: Да, вероятно, хорошая идея. И при варианте когда мы находимся за огромным заводом- направляя лучи в случайных направлениях и считая сумму того что увидели мы сначала, хотя и улетим далеко от него, но потом случайным образом(попадая в положительные точки, если только завод не закрывает их полностью сместимся и начнем движение в обход.  Решается вопрос локальных минимумов- по крайней мере того что в вопросе. Можете что-то сказать о скорости такого метода?

Comment: 1) Можно смотреть насквозь через несколько зданий
2) По поводу скоростей - RTX:On :) Видеокарты такое любят. Так что думаю, будет быстро.

Comment: О нет! Таким образом(трассировкой) мы попадаем в локальный минимум, если расположены так, что видим перед собой 2 завода между которыми виднеется привлекательный объект...